# how to cancel MuiTreeItem-group margin-left?

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, tree

i am using MUI tree,and i want to cancel the margin-left of the second layer of MuiTreeItem-group

I tried to use makeStyles to solve it, but it doesn't seem to work

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    ".MuiCollapse-root .MuiCollapse-vertical .MuiTreeItem-group": {
      marginLeft: '0px',
    },
  }
}))
```

Then I try to use @global to modify, but it will cause other layers to be modified together

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
   
    "@global": {
      ".MuiTreeItem-group": {
        marginLeft: '0px'
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

[image]

The effect I hope is that only the second layer can be modified

[image]

Comment: So you want first level items and second level items to have no indent, but all levels below that to maintain their normal indent?

Comment: yes! and i want to remove hover event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `.MuiTreeItem-group` left margin by using the [CSS child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to directly target the second level.  For example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    "& > .MuiTreeItem-root > .MuiTreeItem-group": {
      marginLeft: "0px"
    }
  }
}));
```

Which would produce the following effect:
[image: example treeview image]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rhn5xf?file=/demo.tsx:307-445

Comment: Thanks you, look helpful!! BTW, how cam i remove the hover event?

Comment: @jan are you looking to do this for all items or just the second level items?

Comment: i want to remove all items hover event

Comment: @jan I've updated the CodeSandbox to remove hover -- refresh it to see my updates

Comment: it's me again.., I want to know how to cancel the one-way first items collapsing function